# Create a variable containing different words to use with filter and grepl functions

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, grepl

I have different datasets where I use following functions to filter them:

DF_HoC is and example of one dataset.

```
DF_HoC_Digi = filter(DF_HoC, grepl("Big data|machine learning|data analytics|data scientist|data analyst|data warehouse|business intelligence| bi |data science|artificial intelligence| ai | iot |internet of things|information systems|information system|deep learning|database|data management|cloud computing|digitalised|digitalized|digitalize|digitalise|digital|digitalisation|digitalization|digitized|digitize|digitised|digitised",text,ignore.case = TRUE))
DF_HoC_DATABASE = filter(DF_HoC, grepl("database",text,ignore.case = TRUE))
DF_HoC_IT = filter(DF_HoC, grepl(" IT ",text,ignore.case = FALSE))
```

I use the same words to filter the different datasets, hence why I would like to create a variable that is working the same as: 
`("Big data|machine learning|data analytics|data scientist|data analyst|data warehouse|business intelligence| bi |data science|artificial intelligence ... )`

I would really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: Please give a small example for us to work with.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).